# how to ios app new version upload on appstore with different system

Tags: ios

ios app has upload on appstore with different system and now i want to upload new version of this on appstore with different system.
because when app upload on appstore then we have to make certificate,provisioning profile by mac.Alll mac have different profile for upload the app on appstore

how to upload the app on appstore?
how to make provsioning profile and certificate for appstore?

Comment: `1. Export the Private key from another computer, and install in your system.` `2. If you don't have any Private key, you have option to create a new Key and Certificate.` `3. You can also Revoke last certificate used to upload the app, and create new with your key.`

Comment: if i revoke last certificate but app is already live then any problem?

Comment: i have try  3 hours our own certificate create and provisioning profile with same bundle id but appstore has raise issues that code signatue invalid and appstore apple certicate is not valid

Comment: You need to add your team in Build Settings and let XCode sync you project, then try to choose Profile from your list, it should work.